# Open symbolic link file as rb, and not the file it is pointing to. (or generating it in buffer)

Tags: django, python-3.x

How could I possible open a symbolic link and get the content of the file instead of the file it is pointing to?

By doing:

```
with open('/home/symlink.txt', 'rb') as f:
    data=f.read()
```

If the symbolic link points to `/foo/faa.txt`, the variable `data` will contain the content of `faa.txt`. This is a big security and file problem from my server because I'm generating zip archives.

If for example, a folder contains multiple symbolic links with different names to avoid duplicating files, the zip archive will contain multiple files instead of multiple symbolic links!

I hope to be clear enough!

---

An extra explanation:

The point of this is to allow downloading symlinks in a django server. The way of returning files is the following one:

```
response = HttpResponse()
response.write(data))
return response
```

This means that `data` must contain the content that the user will download. I can not just give it a path. So what I need to do is to give it a symbolic link. The problem is that reading a symbolic link makes python read the content where it is pointing to instead of its real content. In a few words, the user downloads the real file instead of the symbolic link!

---

A possible solution to this would be to get the path where the symlink points to, and then generate the link in the buffer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are 2 questions here: How can you read a symlink from the filesystem, and how can you store this in a .zip file such that it will be recreated when you unzip it.

### Reading a symlink

The contents of a symlink are defined here:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/symlink.7.html

> A symbolic link is a special type of file whose contents are a string that is the pathname of another file, the file to which the link refers

You can read that path by using `os.readlink` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.readlink) - this is analogous to C's `readlink` function.

It's also important to note that these symlinks aren't distinguished by their content or file attributes, but by the fact that the file entry on disk points to a string rather than a file object:

> In other words, a symbolic link is a pointer to another name, and not to an underlying object.

This means that there isn't really a "file" you could store in the ZIP. So how do the existing zip & unzip utilities do it?

### Storing a symlink in a zip file

The spec for the ZIP format is here: https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT

Note that section 4.5.7 (defining UNIX Extra Field) says:

> The variable length data field will contain file type specific data.  Currently the only values allowed are the original "linked to" file names for hard or symbolic links, and the major and minor device node numbers for character and block device nodes.  [...]  Link files will have the name of the original file stored.

This means that to store a symlink, all you need to do is add the UNIX extra field block to the data you are writing (these appear to live immediately after the filename is written, and you need to set the extra field length accordingly), and populate its "Variable length data field" with the path you get from `readlink`. The content you store for the node will be empty.

If you're using a library to generate the zip data (recommended!), it will probably have an abstraction available for that. If not, I'd suggest you put in a feature request!

Of course, most existing zip and unzip utilities follow the same definition, which is why you are able to zip and unzip symbolic links as if they were regular files.

Comment: Yep, I know it is easy to get the path, but then I can not just simply add  the path to the zip file. And as far as I know,  I can generate a symlink with python but it will create it over the hard drive and not my virtual zip file. I need to have the symbolic link content in a variable inside my code!

Comment: See my updated explanation - you will need to find out how symlinks are stored in the zip format (likely a special flag you need to set)

Comment: I'm sorry but if you generate a zip from a folder containing symbolic links, when extracting the folder the symbolic links are there! That means that when the system tools generate the zip they do not read the real file (that works with all the compression formats I know, zip, tar.gz, 7z, etc..).

Comment: After doing some more researches, I think that you are right, actually  for compressing links there are special methods. Unfortunately I think that I do need to get some file so the user can download it (in case the user only want to download a link).